# C writing a random matrix to a file and then reading and copying said matrix from file using formatted I/O

Tags: c, file, matrix, scanf

Thanks for all the help I have gotten here before.

In the below program I want to create a random matrix, print it to the screen, write it to a file, then scan a copy of that matrix from the file and print the copy to the screen, everything works except for when I try to read from the file, the algorithm in my code is is incorrect I think,

the scanf function fails i dont know why....

```
double *matrix_read(FILE *fptr, double *mat, int m, int n ) ;

double *matrix_read(FILE *fptr,double *mat, int m, int n ) {
     int i,j;
     double *ptr,x ;
     ptr=mat;

    if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot Open File");
    }
    rewind(fptr);
    fscanf( fptr,"\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n", &m, &n) ;
    mat = (double *) malloc( sizeof( double ) * m * n ) ;

    for ( i=0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( j=0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            fscanf(fptr, "  %5.2lf", &x );
            *ptr++=x;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    return mat ;   
}
```

In my `main`, the functions are called as follows:

```
rand_matrix(MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols );  /* populates matrix with random                     data */

print_matrix(MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ;  /* prints the matrix */

matrix_write( fptr, MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ; /* writes matrix to     file*/

_flushall();
getchar();

MATRIX1.matrix=matrix_read( fptr, MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ; /* reads     above matrix from file as a copy */

print_matrix(MATRIX1.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ; /* prints this copyed matrix*/
```

when printing the copyed matrix I get a bunch of garble, massive numbers (ie 1259000000000000000000) I think these are memory location names or something, can someone help me fix my `read_matrix()` function?

Thank you very much.

Below is my full code(it compiles).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <conio.h>

double random() ;
double *rand_matrix( double *mat, int m, int n ) ;
void print_matrix( double *mat, int m, int n ) ;    
void matrix_write(FILE *fptr, double *mat, int m, int n ) ;    
double *matrix_read(FILE *fptr, double *mat, int m, int n ) ;    

int main()
{

    struct matrep {
      unsigned rows,cols;
      double *matrix;
    } MATRIX,MATRIX1,MATRIX2;

    int check = 0 ;
    FILE *fptr;

    printf( "\n\nMatrix Manipulations Program" );

    do {
        printf( "\n\nEnter matrix dimensions : rows x columns : " );
        check = scanf( "%d x %d", &MATRIX.rows, &MATRIX.cols );
        _flushall();
    } while ( check != 2 || MATRIX.rows < 1 || MATRIX.cols < 1 ) ;

    MATRIX.matrix = (double *) malloc( sizeof( double ) * MATRIX.rows * MATRIX.cols ) ;

    if ( !MATRIX.matrix ){
        printf( "\n\nSTOP : unable to allocate memory - exiting program") ;
        exit( 1 ) ;
    }

    rand_matrix(MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols );  /* populates matrix with random data */

    print_matrix(MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ;  /* prints the matrix */

    matrix_write( fptr, MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ; /* writes matrix to     file*/

    _flushall();
    getchar();

    MATRIX1.matrix=matrix_read( fptr, MATRIX.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ; /* reads     above matrix from file as a copy */

    print_matrix(MATRIX1.matrix, MATRIX.rows, MATRIX.cols ) ; /* prints this copyed matrix*/

    _flushall();
    getchar();
}

/***********************************************************/

double random()
{
    static int seeded = 0;
    double val ;

    if ( !seeded )
    {
       srand( time(NULL) ) ;
       seeded = 1;
    }

    val = ((double)rand())/ (double)RAND_MAX * 100.0 ;

    return val ;
}

/***********************************************************/

double *rand_matrix( double *mat, int m, int n ) 
{
    double *ptr ;
    int i, j ;

    ptr = mat ;

    for ( i=0; i < m; i++ ){
        for ( j=0; j < n; j++ ){
            *ptr++ = random() ;
        }
    }
    return mat ; 
}

/***********************************************************/

void print_matrix( double *mat, int m, int n ) 
{
    double *ptr ;
    int i, j ;

    if ( mat==0 || m==0 || n==0 )
    {
       printf("\n\nEmpty matrix" );
       return ;       
    }

    ptr = mat ;

    printf( "\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n", m, n) ;

    for ( i=0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( j=0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "\t%5.2lf", *ptr++ );
        }
        printf( "\n" ) ;
    }

}

/***********************************************************/
void matrix_write(FILE *fptr,double *mat, int m, int n ) {
     int i,j;
    if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.txt","w"))==NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot Open File");
    }
    fprintf( fptr,"\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n", m, n) ;

    for ( i=0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( j=0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "  %5.2lf", *mat++ );
        }
        fprintf(fptr, "\n" ) ;
    }
    fclose(fptr);    
}

/***********************************************************/
double *matrix_read(FILE *fptr,double *mat, int m, int n ) {
     int i,j;
     double *ptr,x ;
     ptr=mat;

    if((fptr=fopen("matrixA.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot Open File");
    }
    rewind(fptr);
    fscanf( fptr,"\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n", &m, &n) ;
    mat = (double *) malloc( sizeof( double ) * m * n ) ;

    for ( i=0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( j=0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            fscanf(fptr, "  %5.2lf", &x );
            *pt++r=x;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    return mat ;   
}
```

Comment: `*pt++r=x;` in `matrix_read()` ?

Comment: Note: at the end of the program, you must `free()` the `malloc()`'ed memory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as so often, in the memory management.  There are a lot of other oddities in the code, though:

```
double *matrix_read(FILE *fptr, double *mat, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    double *ptr, x;
    ptr = mat;  // This points to the matrix passed into the function

    // Why pass fptr as an argument if the first thing you do is open a file?
    // Especially since you close it at the end
    if ((fptr = fopen("matrixA.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot Open File");
        return 0;  // Get out; do not use the file stream!
    }
    rewind(fptr);  // This is unnecessary; a file is opened for reading at the start
    if (fscanf(fptr, "\n\nrows %d, columns %d\n\n", &m, &n) != 2)
    {
        puts("Failed to read dimensions of array");
        return 0;
    }
    mat = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * m * n);
    // Now you've got a new matrix, but you did not reinitialize ptr to use it!
```

There's also some moderately random spacing around operators.  Consistency is paramount; given that, spaces after commas and not before; spaces after semi-colons and not before; spaces around binary operators.

Also, you have a structure for the matrix, yet you don't pass that structure to your functions.   Your code would probably be better if you did use it.  OTOH, you'd have to move the definition of `struct matrep` outside of `main()` so it could be seen by the functions.

```
int matrix_read(struct matrep *mat)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    unsigned m, n;

    if ((fptr = fopen("matrixA.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot Open File %s\n", "matrixA.txt");
        return -1;
    }
    if (fscanf(fptr, "\n\nnrows %u, columns %u\n\n", &m, &n) != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read dimensions\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // ?? free(mat.matrix); ?? /* to release previously allocated memory */
    mat.matrix = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * m * n);
    if (mat.matrix == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %d*%d matrix\n", m, n);
        return -1;
    }
    double *ptr = mat.matrix;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            double x;
            if (fscanf(fptr, "  %5.2lf", &x) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read element matrix[%d,%d]\n", i, j);
                free(mat.matrix);
                mat.matrix = 0;
                mat.columns = 0;
                mat.rows = 0;
                return -1;
            }
            *ptr++ = x;
        }
    }
    fclose(fptr);
    mat.columns = m;
    mat.rows = n;

    return 0;  // Success   
}
```

There are many changes, but the most significant is that by passing the `struct matrep` into the function, the code can indicate the size of the matrix that it read to the calling code.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ( i=0; i < m; i++ )
{
    for ( j=0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "  %5.2lf", &x );
        *ptr=x;
    }
}
```

While your whole code was too long to read, this section is definitely wrong. You have to increment the pointer at some time, or only the first element will get initialized. Try:

```
*ptr++ = x;
```

`valgrind` is a great tool to detect such errors, it will throw an error when you access (or print, in your case) uninitialized memory.

Comment: I have fixed that error however the code still throws up the same, or very similar uninitialized memory